# How to Control loops in visual basic.. I'm using it at login attempts

Tags: vb.net

I have this project and I'm trying to create a Login Attempt/s with the shortest code possible, so I tried using loops. Here's the codings

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim attempts = 3
    Do
        If txtUsername.Text = username And txtPassword.Text = password Then
            MessageBox.Show("ACCESS GRANTED")
            Me.Hide()
            MainMenu.Show()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("ACCESS DENIED")
            txtUsername.Text = "input username"
            txtPassword.Text = "input password"
            attempts = attempts - 1
        End If

    Loop Until attempts <= 0
    MessageBox.Show("Maximum Login Attempts Reached!")
End Sub
```

But seems like I'm in a paradox or an infinite loop. I'm thinking of controlling the loops like continue; and break; like java so.. is there any ways I can do that in visual basic?

Comment: did you check if it ever reaches the else statement?

Comment: yes it did, It starts once MsgBox(Access Denied) shows 3 times, (Sorry my question/statement was wrong, it's not infinite) Variable "attempts" decrements, so it reaches the else statement

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.NET? VBA has nothing to do with VS 2015. Please use the appropriate tags for your questions.

Comment: sorry I'm a newbie. It's Windows Form Application with VB language using Visual Studio IDE. I dunno vba or vb.net, I thought vba was vb language. So sorry to confuse you.

Comment: The user has to enter the name+password again, then reclick the button.  So this cannot be a loop inside this Click event handler.  The `attempt` variable must be a moved out of the method.

Answer (score 1):

as Hans points out, you'll need to move the `attempt` outside of the method. Simply you create the variable within the form Class and then progress the attempts with each onClick event. Hopefully this makes sense, the below code should give you the desired result!

```
Dim Attempts As Integer = 0

Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Attempts += 1
    If Attempts > 3 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Maximum Login Attempts Reached!")
        Exit Sub
        'User has tried too many times - just keep exiting the method, or you can use
        'Application.Exit()
        'This will just quit the program..
    End If

    If txtUsername.Text = username And txtPassword.Text = password Then
        MessageBox.Show("ACCESS GRANTED")
        Me.Hide()
        MainMenu.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("ACCESS DENIED")
        txtUsername.Text = "input username"
        txtPassword.Text = "input password"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want the application to just exit, then uncommeent the `Application.Exit` and comment out the `Exit Sub`
if you want to reset attempts (for whatever reason) you can add in a call to `Attempts = 0`

Hth Chicken

Comment: Got It.. Thank you. Turns out I can't use loops with this, instead an If-Else, I get it now. I got the idea of looping it from my previous project it's an console application and doesn't have GUI so the code logic are different. Thank You :)